# SP online: how to delete a wrong js in the display templates

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, display-template

I have created a copy of a js file of a display template. I have tried to delete it with no success even with sharepoint designer.

How do I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: Kindly attach screen capture with your question & give brief description of your issue.

Comment: Are you able to check it in?

Comment: if i check in it tells me the file has been deleted, which is not true

Comment: dunno for sure.. maybe SharePoint "releases" the file when you disable Publishing on the whole Library

Comment: try opening the masterpage lib with "open with explorer" feature as well

Comment: done it, even if it 'deletes' it, when i close it and refresh the file is still there

Answer (score 0):

You should first refresh your current folder in a designer it will list out the template files (.html and .js). Try to delete the .html file from the list and system will delete the .js file or only .js file. This is working in my case.

If you see only one .JS file and not able to delete from designer you can try from browser also.

- Go to root web site setting.
- Go to "Master pages and page layouts".
- Go to "Display Templates" folder.
- Delete the file from here.

Let me know if I missing any point here.

Comment: this is the root web site and your point 2,3,4 is where I went (the image is taken from that folder

Comment: I see from the screenshot it looks like from designer.

Comment: The error seems also like when you are trying to delete .js file when there is an associated template .html file exists.

Comment: my problem is that by mistake I created a copy of the .js file so I have the js file only. What do I do? Create a copy of the html?

Comment: You can copy the .html also and make sure when you copying the file name should match with your .js file. And then delete .html file system should deletes the .js file. This is an observation in my site and working.